# How to solve "Unhandled exception type BeansException"

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am a beginner at Spring Batch. I am following this [guide](http://www.techavalanche.com/2011/08/21/spring-batch-hello-world-in-memory/) to create a HelloWorld of Spring Batch. In the class with main method when I was trying to get Application Context by using `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("...")`, the IDE shows an error message saying

> Unhandled exception type BeansException

I cannot solve that error even though I have a catch block that catches all types of exceptions. Refer to the code block below:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            //error message appears here
            AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("simpleJob.xml");

            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addString("Date", "12/02/2011");
            jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());

            JobExecution jobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), builder.toJobParameters());
            System.out.println(jobExecution.toString());
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Then, I tried to solve it by `import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;` and tried to catch `BeansException`. Although the unhandled BeansException error was solved but another error message appeared:

> No exception of type BeansException can be thrown; an exception type
>   must be a subclass of throwable

Refer to the code block below:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("simpleJob.xml");

            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addString("Date", "12/02/2011");
            jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());

            JobExecution jobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), builder.toJobParameters());
            System.out.println(jobExecution.toString());
        }
        //error message appears here
        catch(BeansException e) {
            //do something
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

What is the correct way to solve this error?

Additional note: I do not have my own class named BeansException.

**Edit: Stack trace (proceed with error option):**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    No exception of type BeansException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

    at SpringBatchHelloWorld.BatchLauncher.main(BatchLauncher.java:29)
```

Comment: Check, do you have something like `spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar` in your class path. Of course, there is has to be your real version instead of  `4.2.4`.

Comment: i have spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar; spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar; spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar; spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar. Note: I can only import `org.springframework.beans.BeansException` after I have included spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: do i need to include spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar?

Comment: Yes, all Spring jars should have same version. So, if you have `spring-context` of `4.2.4.RELEASE`, `spring-core` should be `4.2.4.RELEASE` as well.

Comment: The latest version for spring-batch-core is 3.0.6 hence I changed all the jar to 3.0.6 but the same error still appears

Comment: I meant just `spring-beans`, `spring-context` and `spring-core`. All should have same version. It can be 4.2.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @KenBekov Wow awesome!! After I have included spring-beans, spring-context and spring-core of version 4.2.5, all error messages are gone. Thanks! Would you like to formulate a solution below? I can do it if you do not want to

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, you can formulate solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Ken Bekov's comments to the question, I was able to solve this problem and I formulated this solution to officially give this question an answer. Credits should be given to Ken Bekov.

**Solution:**
The problem was due to different version of .jar files included in the build path. The .jar files that should be included are: `spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`, `spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar` and `spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar` (notice the same version number - 4.2.5).

As for `spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar`, `spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar` and others, they do not necessarily need to have the same version number (4.2.5).

After the correct .jar files were included, there won't even be an "Unhandled exception type BeansException" error message for `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("...");`

Answer (score 0):

1. delete existing jars files form .m2\repository\org\springframework folder.
2. do clean build by using same version of spring-context.jar, spring-beans.jar and spring-core.jar